# This sculpture in google maps looks very familliar - what is it?

Tags: object-identification

I spotted this sculpture on [google maps](https://www.google.com.tw/maps/@24.9759622,121.5013363,3a,45.9y,303.59h,81.06t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sw09O1CXxtjaKfjuWpinshA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=en). You can see it slightly left of center behind the weeds...

**Who or what is it?**

[image]

**Update:** Here is a new photo 19-Sep-2016:

[image]

Comment: What the hell is with all the scooters on this road? Have we wandered into the scooter district?

Comment: @Valorum In [subtropical climates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taipei#Climate) it's quite normal to see a lot of scooters and two-wheelers in the cities. They get around better, are cheaper and use less gas than cars.

Comment: it looks like a space marine of warhammer 40k

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It appears to be a [Mondoshawan](http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Mondoshawan) from the film "The Fifth Element"

Here's the bobble-head version

[image]

and a slightly better view now that they've cleared the trees back.

[image]

Comment: Aha!!! Indeed - it's been a very long time, but like they (actually) say, "time is not important." Now to figure out what it's doing there - waiting for something?

Comment: @uhoh - **"[Only life important](https://theemergist.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/aliens-from-the-fifth-element.png)"**

Comment: I never noticed that huge white round thing. Is that their version of the zipper?

Comment: @svick - You might want to ask that as a new question. I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: It's a flashlight actually.